# Input being called unexpectedly. Was working yesterday but not since python3.9

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am building scraper that are suppose to function one after the other. The intention is that the user is promoted for input at the beginning and the scraper does its job and produces 3 excel files.

It was working fine yesterday but it keeps prompting me for input every time the input is passed from one scraper to the next. What changed during that time is that I was working with a colleague and we decided to use Pipenv to have the same environment which required me to upgrade to python 3.9.2. In addition to that now when I try to run the scraper outside of the Pipenv shell I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
> Which I assume means that the paths got messed up when I installed python3.9.2 and the pipenv shell.

The code is located in 3 files.

The execution file purelily.py

```
from scraper_leads_firmenacb import scrape_firmenabc
from scraper_url import add_url
from qualify_leads import qualify_leads_fn

def scrape_leads():
    filename = scrape_firmenabc()
    filename = add_url(filename)
    wordlist = ""
    filename = qualify_leads_fn(filename, wordlist)

    return filename

scrape_leads()
```

Which is meant to coordinate the scraper. Then there are the individual scrapers.

```
def scrape_firmenabc():
    companytype = input("Enter the company type: ")
    location = input("Enter the location (Bezirk/Ort/Plz): ")

    # Scrape information using selenium 

    # Exporting table in excel format
    filename = companytype + "_" + location
    df.to_excel("leads/" + filename + ".xlsx")

    return filename

scrape_firmenabc()
```

And:

```
def add_url(filename):
    # Importing data with urls
    df = pd.read_excel("leads/" + filename + ".xlsx")
    
    # Scrape thing with selenium ... ...

    filename = filename + "_plus"
    df_t.to_excel("leads/" + filename + ".xlsx")

    return filename

filename = get_leadsfile_ql()
add_url(filename)
```

Then qualify_leads.py which is practically the same:

```
def qualify_leads_fn(filename, wordlist):

    # Open leadsfile
    df = pd.read_excel("leads/" + filename + ".xlsx")

    # Scrape thing with selenium ...

    filename = filename + "_qualified"
    df_t.to_excel("leads/" + filename + ".xlsx")

    return filename

wordlist = get_wordlist_ql()
filename = get_leadsfile_ql()
qualify_leads_fn(filename, wordlist)
```

And finally there is the file that prompts the user for input, get_user_input.py

```
def get_wordlist_ql():
    wordlistfile = input("Insert wordlist: ")

def get_leadsfile_ql():
    leadsfile = input("\nInsert leads: ")
```

This is kind of the minimum requirements to understanding the application. However the rest of the code is located in my git if there. https://github.com/ChristopherPHolder/outreach_automation

Answer (score 0):

Seem topic when I think about it now but I imported files where there was a call to a function at the end of the file. Therefore it was calling the get_user_input functions every a file was loaded.

I changed the design of the app so there is one function called operator that allows the user to select operations to call.

Then removed all other function calls from all files. Seems like a smarted design choice.